# How to send templated emails?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postmark

How does one send a templated Postmark message on ASP.NET? I'd imagine it would be done in this way:

```
TemplatedPostmarkMessage message = new TemplatedPostmarkMessage
{
    From = "demo@demo.com",
    To = "someone@else.com",
    TemplateId = 1738,
    TemplateModel = some_passed_in_model
};
```

The question now arises, what exactly is TemplateModel? From the API on Postmark's site, it seems like a JSON object, but in the definition from the DLL, it's as follows:

```
public object TemplateModel { get; set; }
```

I tried creating my own object with variable names that correspond to those on the Postmark template, however that does not work (it just sends a blank template). Postmark also does not have any documentation on how to use TemplatedPostmarkMessage in ASP.NET yet.

Comment: did you try an anonymous object? they are often used with json, eg `var foo  = new { bar = "blah" } `

Comment: api is here : http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-api-templates.html hmm

Comment: * also I think you might need to create a template prior to using it *?

Answer (score 0):

We send a dictionary of <string, object>, I believe you can use more complex models but a dictionary will get the job done.